# Get deepest or element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My questions is regarding XML to LINQ where i have something as following structure:

```
<Or>
   <value />
      <Or>
         <value />
         <Or> //this is the deepest "or" element i should get in this case
           <value />
           <value />
         </Or>
    </Or>
</Or>
```

Which i basically build programmatically through the recrusion, but my questions i rather how to get the deepest Or element?

If i do:

`elements.Element("Or"),` it just gets me the first top element Or ....

Waitin for response.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple equally deep `Or` elements at different places in the document?

Comment: there wont be, there will be always be one parent and then one parent or and then child or etc

Comment: which of these three elements is deepest?

Comment: Updated the post, that is the or which is the deepest and i need to have it :), although as i said it is build recursievly and it can be deaper so i dont want to do something like, element.Element("or").Element("Or") ... etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //XDocument.Parse(filename);
var deepestOr = xDoc.Descendants("Or")
                    .First(or => !or.Descendants("Or").Any());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
var bench =  XElement.Parse(@"<Or><value /><Or><value /><Or><value /><value /></Or></Or></Or>");    

var lastOne = bench.Descendants("Or").Where( n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element).Last();
```

Result:

```
<Or>
  <value />
  <value />
</Or>
```

No matter how deep it is

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Or><value /><Or><value /><Or><value /><value /></Or></Or></Or>");

// take 'Or' node which contains no 'Of' nodes
var deepest = doc.Descendants("Or").Where(node => node.Descendants("Or").Count() == 0);
```